# PHP PDO: Use fetchAll() FETCH_CLASS but only allow named properties

Tags: php, database, pdo

I am reading multiple database results with `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, Rating::class)` into a class. Now my database has an additional column which I have not added to the php class. The `fetchAll()` function however also fills this class with the attribute.

It seems I need to remove the `__set()` call. I also saw `FETCH_INTO` but that only works for single rows. Any suggestion?

Comment: In your query, only select the columns you want in your objects.

Comment: Rather, you have to make your __set more intelligent and check whether such a property exists before setting it.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular that is a simple, but good idea!

Comment: @YourCommonSense How would I do that? My class has no special __set method, I've just read that this is kinda a php default function. (I am new to this)